# Rubymine debugger has stopped breaking on my breakpoints

Tags: debugging, rubymine

I've been using rubymine for the past few months and everything has worked fine, debugging worked no problem.  All of a sudden last week rubymine will not stop at my breakpoints.  I rolled back my code base to a date I knew the debugger was working, in case some gems were added that interfered, and that still didn't help.  I also didn't mess with any rubymine settings.

Any else have this happen to them?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have gem 'debugger' in you Gemfile? it sometimes cause that.

Comment: That line is commented out.  Debugging worked great for months, until all of a sudden it stopped in the middle of the day.

Comment: I have the same issue. Even removing .idea directory did not helped. Rubymine 7.0.

Comment: Ok, I unistalled all debugging gem and installed new versions and debugger started to work again.